# Android Bluetooth Set Timeout for BluetoothSocket.connect();

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there any chance to set a timeout for

```
BluetoothSocket.connect();
```

So that the method cancels after a certain amount of time ?

Thanks !

Comment: what do you mean by timeout?
if you want to turn off bluetooth connection after sometime run a thread, or timer

Comment: I want to cancel the connect attempt if my device can't connect in a certain amount of time.

Comment: Make a handler and post a delayed runnable that cancels the connect thread if it does not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to cancel the connect attempt if device is not connected in a certain amount of time, then run a thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something after 5 second
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok seems to be clear. But what should I do after 5 seconds, when I want to abort the connection attempt ?